# Why am I getting an incompatible pointer type warning from this structure?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm confused as to why I am getting an incompatible pointer type warning from my code. My debugger says that the issue is with the line

```
nodeToInsert->next = *head;
```

The particular line is a part of the function

```
user_t *moveNameToHead();
```

I don't know why this error is occurring since both pointers of of type user_t. This is the relevant code for the issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 20

typedef struct user {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int numOfFriends;
    char nameOfFriend[NAME_LENGTH];
    struct node *next; //used for our linked list
} user_t;

//prototypes of functions to be used
void addQueryType();
user_t *createNewNameNode(char *name);
user_t *moveNameToHead();

int main() {
/// some code that eventually calls addQueryType ///
}

void addQueryType() {
char nameOfPersonA[NAME_LENGTH], nameOfPersonB[NAME_LENGTH];

//record names user enters
scanf("%s", nameOfPersonA);
scanf("%s", nameOfPersonB);

user_t *head, *temporary;

temporary = createNewNameNode(nameOfPersonA);
moveNameToHead(&head, temporary);
temporary = createNewNameNode(nameOfPersonB);
moveNameToHead(&head, temporary);


}

//will create nodes for us on a needs basis
user_t *createNewNameNode(char *name) {
    user_t *node = malloc(sizeof(user_t));
    strcpy(node->name, name);
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

//moves newly added name to head of the linked list
user_t *moveNameToHead(user_t **head, user_t *nodeToInsert) {
    nodeToInsert->next = *head;
    *head = nodeToInsert;
    return nodeToInsert;
}
```

I'm trying to create a linked list with the user names. The names are turned into nodes of the list and then are then fed into a function that turns the most recent name into the head of the list. The issue is I don't know why I'm getting the incompatible pointer type warning.

I've tried changing *head to a char type thinking that maybe that would have something to do with it since the items in the list are names, but that returned the same error along with others.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `next` is `struct node *` and `*head` is  `user_t *`.

Comment: Typo: `struct node *next;` --> `struct user_t *next;`

Comment: @October171It will be correct to define  the data member next like struct user *next;

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry, I meant in `moveNameToHead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your typo:

```
typedef struct user {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int numOfFriends;
    char nameOfFriend[NAME_LENGTH];
    struct user *next; //used for our linked list
} user_t;
```

Then it works

Comment: @Konrad At least it starts to compile without warnings

Comment: Never mind, you’re right. I didn’t see that OP had redefined `head` differently.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is throwing you a warning because, `user_t::next` and `user_t *head` are defined as different types.

`head` is of type `user_t *`  while `user_t::next` is of type `struct node *`. Which seems to be an undefined struct. Consider changing `user_t::next` to be defined as type `struct user *`.

Example:

```
typedef struct user {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int numOfFriends;
    char nameOfFriend[NAME_LENGTH];
    struct user *next; //used for our linked list
} user_t;
```